# Excel VBA - Manual input of data in data validation cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have  worksheet which has various validation lists, however for all these lists I need to have the option of users own entry in the cell.

I know you can uncheck the box however because my worksheet gets regenerated on a regular basis I need to achieve this programatically. Anyone have any idea how to do this? Here is the code I have that creates the drop down lists:

```
    For u = 1 To SpecDependencies.count
        SpecDepList = SpecDepList & "," & SpecDependencies(u) & " - " & SpecDepDate(u)
    Next

    With CRC.Cells(ECURowInCRC, 8).Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula1:=SpecDepList
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputMessage = "View Spec Dependancies"
        '.ErrorMessage = "No value selected"
        .ShowInput = True
        '.ShowError = True
    End With

    End If

    SpecDepList = ""
    Set SpecDependencies = New Collection
    Set SpecDepDate = New Collection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've almost got it in the code you posted, just change `.ShowError` to false and the user can input anything and not be warned

```
For u = 1 To SpecDependencies.count
    SpecDepList = SpecDepList & "," & SpecDependencies(u) & " - " & SpecDepDate(u)
Next

With CRC.Cells(ECURowInCRC, 8).Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:=SpecDepList
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputMessage = "View Spec Dependancies"
    '.ErrorMessage = "No value selected"
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = False
End With

End If

SpecDepList = ""
Set SpecDependencies = New Collection
Set SpecDepDate = New Collection
```

Comment: No problem at all buddy!